# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'endpoint'

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket

I am trying to fetch live data through websocket using code

```
from bitmex_websocket import *
# import logging
# from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
from time import sleep

crypto = "XBTUSD"
api_key = "XXXXX"
api_secret = "YYYYY"
sleeping = 5

def run():
    ws = BitMEXWebsocket(endpoint="https://testnet.bitmex.com/api/v1",
                         symbol=crypto, api_key=api_key, api_secret=api_secret)
    logger.info("Instrument data: %s" % ws.get_instrument())
    while(ws.ws.sock.connected):
        logger.info("Ticker: %s" % ws.get_ticker())
        sleep(sleeping)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

This code used to work until this morning and fetch live prices every 5 secs but   now it gives me an error

```
2019-01-05 12:47:53 DEBUG [bitmex_websocket._settings_base:24] INFO
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Test files\T2.py", line 25, in <module>
    run()
  File "F:\Test files\T2.py", line 17, in run
    symbol=crypto, api_key=api_key, api_secret=api_secret)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'endpoint'
[Finished in 0.5s]
```

I am new to python and this is the first time i have ever worked with live data, i have tried everything i can think of but i am unable to solve it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking questions about Python and showing code, please make sure that the code is properly indented. One or the purposes of a [mcve] is that we should be able to basically copy-paste it and try it ourselves. If the code needs to be modified to make it work, there's less of a chance you will get good help. Also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: And when asking questions about errors, please include the *full* and *complete* output of the error, and add a comment in the code where the error(s) happen.

Comment: I am sorry, didnt know that. i edited it.

Comment: Can we see your import statements from the top of your document? And what version of python are you using?

Comment: Could you add import lines too. Basically the object BitMEXWebsocket cannot be created with endpoint parameter. Have you read the doc of this object?

Comment: I added the imports and i am using python 3.7

Comment: Yeah i did as i said the same code use to work untill this morning so maybe they made some recent changes to it? is that possible?

Comment: Official doc itself has a parameter endpoint https://github.com/BitMEX/api-connectors/tree/master/official-ws/python

Comment: Excepted indentation, running your MCVE does not throw this error but `Error : Handshake status 401` which means it can connect and credentials are not valid, roughly speaking it might work as this. Maybe you should update your package. I just got it installed and it works: `python -m pip install -U bitmex-ws`

Comment: i tried updating but its says this : `C:\Users>python -m pip install -U bitmex-ws
Requirement already up-to-date: bitmex-ws in c:\python3.7\lib\site-packages (0.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: websocket-client==0.46.0 in c:\python3.7\lib\site-packages (from bitmex-ws) (0.46.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six in c:\python3.7\lib\site-packages (from websocket-client==0.46.0->bitmex-ws) (1.11.0)` ...I also created fresh apis but still cant solve it

Comment: Okay i had a file named bitmex_websocket installed . Uninstalling worked for me!Thanks for help everyone